# Add [title] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Models\Post]

Tags: mysql, api, laravel-8

I keep on getting this error:

> `Add [title] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Models\Post].`

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillabel = [
        'title',
        'slug',
        'likes',
        'content'
    ];
}
```

Create Posts table

```
public function up()
    {

        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->id();

            $table->string('title');

            $table->string('slug');

            $table->integer('likes') ->default(0);

            $table->string('content')->nullable();

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

api.php

```
Route::get('/posts', function(){

    $post = Post::create([
        'title'=> 'my first post',
        'slug'=> 'my-first-post'
    ]);

    return $post;
});
```

Comment: its typo, change `$fillabel` to `$fillable`

Comment: O MY WORD : ) thank you Devsi just fixed the problem "Spelling is sop important and always the last thing I check haha I'll make a note of the in the future thank you "